# Multiple DataSources with Multiple Transaction Managers in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions, datasource

I have three `DataSource`'s (JDBC) defined in the Junit application context file. Two of them need to be transactionally managed; I do not have to chain any of the methods when using these two data sources (they are entirely independent of each other).

I did not have a problem when I used a single transaction manager for `dataSource2`, even though `dataSource3` was being utilized but not managed in the corresponding methods. Nonetheless, upon needing to also manage methods from various DAO classes that solely use `dataSource3`, I added the second transaction -- `txManager2`. The context file contains the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.pkg" />

<bean id="dataSource1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host1:1521:dbsid1" />
<property name="username" value="username1" />
<property name="password" value="password1" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host2:1521:dbsid2" />
<property name="username" value="username2" />
<property name="password" value="password2" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource3"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host3:1521:dbsid3" />
<property name="username" value="username3" />
<property name="password" value="password3" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="txManager1"/>
<property name="dataSource2" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="txManager2"/>
<property name="dataSource3" ref="dataSource3"/>
</bean>
```

Since multiple transaction managers are being defined, I **qualified** them with their own values. As you can see, `dataSource3` is being injected using a setter method:

```
package my.pkg;

@Component
public class MyDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource3;

    // Read only from datasource
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    // Performs reads/updates/inserts from datasource2
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource2")
    public void setDataSource2(DataSource ds) {
        iTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    // Performs reads/updates/inserts from datasource3
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource3")
    public void setDataSource3(DataSource ds) {
        dataSource3 = ds;
        uTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Transactional("txManager1")    
    public String insertProcs() { }

    @Transactional("txManager2")    
    public String updateProcs() { }
}
```

However, upon running the **Junit unit test**, I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager2' defined in class path resource [test-context.xml]: 

Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource3' of bean class 

[org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Bean property 'dataSource3' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter 

type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1363)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource3' of bean class 

    [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Bean property 'dataSource3' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter 

    type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1052)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
```

Any idea where the source of the problem is?

## Update

Based on the answer accepted, the following changes were made to get the intended functionality:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager1"/>

<bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="txManager1"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="txManager2"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3"/>
</bean>
```

`@Qualifier("dataSource")` should have been corrected (typo on my part):

```
    // Read only from datasource
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource1")
    public void setDataSource1(DataSource ds) {
        template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few problems with your configuration:

```
<property name="dataSource2" ref="dataSource2"/>
<property name="dataSource3" ref="dataSource3"/>
```

The **bean names** are different, but **property names** are not. You should change this to:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3"/>
```

E.g.: in setter properties for txManager1 and txManager2 beans respectively.

Second: `@Qualifier("dataSource2")` and `@Qualifier("dataSource3")` are wrong since your are qualifying the TX managers beans, and not the data-source beans.

You can use `@Resource("dataSource2")` and `@Resource("dataSource3")` instead, or qualify the data-source beans as well.

Third: `@Qualifier("dataSource")`. Notice it's not complaint either with a qualifier and a bean's name (note: it's **dataSource1**)

As a last thing, you have defined `tx:annotation-driven`. It expects a transaction manager whose bean name is **transactionManager**. You have failed to give it's bean definition as well, so this will fail either.

Comment: The property names was the issue, and I had forgotten to include the first transaction in `tx:annotation-driven`. The `dataSource` qualifier mistake was a typo (I am leaving it in the question so the answer provided won't be out of place for the future readers).

Comment: Classic explanation :)