# Spring JDBC how to implement multiple datasource with a transaction manager without using JTA

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

After surveyed, the only way to deal with this situation seems to use JTA. What if I would like to use just JDBC. Can it be possible to get it done?
This [reference links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038261/multiple-datasources-with-multiple-transaction-managers-in-spring) is pretty close what I am looking for. Does any one have any idea? That will be really helpful. Thank you. That is a plus if offer example.

The reason why I don't consider ORM is the poor performance when query massive data. Therefore, what I think native SQL plus JDBCTemplate might be suitable for me.

Comment: You can use native queries as part of JPA or most ORM's

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the tradeoffs involved, [ChainedTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html) could be an option.  You'd have a separate transaction manager for each datasource and then a single ChainedTransactionManager that aggregated all of the other TX managers.

It works by sequentially calling each delegate TX manager.  Unlike JTA, it isn't a true two-phase commit and there's the possibility of leaving things in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Dynamic DataSource Routing](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)