# What is a good practice to deploy webservices?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, architecture

Is it a good practice to deploy web services separately or should they be part of the web application? For instance, I am developing a **spring** rest based web service. The function of this service is to, let's say, to get user data.

Each webapplication that queries this web service has it's user data in different schema. So, now the webservice will need to know who is calling it - is it Appilcation A or Application B? If it's AppA, then it should get data from Schema A, if it's AppB, then its another schema. Note, that AppA and AppB are just the same code packed into two different wars and the schema they are supposed to query is supplied from properties file.

In a situation like this, does it make sense to pack the webservice with the webapp code and deploy it under different contexts, so it becomes a duplciate service running in a different context. Or, should it be deployed separately and somehow the AppA and AppB are supposed to identify themselves to this web service?

Comment: What if in future you end up creating AppC, AppD, AppE .... and so on. You will end up in a maintenance hell.

Comment: @Guanxi why would it be a maintenance hell? the code for applications is all the same, just the configuration is different.

Comment: From your description, I don’t see a real need for webservice. From the description my understanding is, to avoid the code duplication you are thinking about a webservice. If it is 2 different schema let AppA and AppB communicate directly to its own data source. This will be good for the future enhancements too.

Comment: Why don't create a library/module to include in every Application instead of an external webservice? The initialization code of this library will get the schema information from parameters and then do all queries inside its code. If your applications shares the same database and the same execution enviroment, I think this is the easiest solution for you.

Comment: @lifeisfoo the reason for external webservice is to expose an API for non-browsing clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement a Data Provider, or DAO as a service. 
To make it -

1. Simple
2. Scalable
3. Maintainence-friendly,
4. Adaptable

You can simply have a single webservice, deployed outside the WebApp(s) and driven off configuration. The configuration itself can be stored as property file, or from a DB. The identifier for the client should be being passed in the webservice request.

This is actually a pretty standard approach implemented to enable optimizations at the Data tier outside of DB, like caching (again driven of configuration), expiry, pooling, etc.

The other option, to include as a shared jar within the webapp, yes, has advantage of code-reuse (which you get with externally deployed service as well), but the following disadvantages outweigh the option.

- Coupling
- Employing optimizations are difficult
- Release management (this also depends upon how your code is organized)
- Versioning.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer below approach, which is in use for 50K concurrent users.

1. Make sure that ***each web service encapsulates both UI and Schema independently*** by executing required business use case. Each web service will have all three layers - Model, View and Controller for that business service. That means your App-A is one web service & App-B is other web service.
2. ***All web services will register and un-register with Master web service***. Master web service is responsible to redirecting user request to appropriate web service like App-A OR App-B.
3. You should have ***cluster of Master web service & cluster of individual web services*** - App-A & App-B
4. In this approach, your ***schema can reside on different database*** instead of single database

**Advantages of this approach:**

1. **Each web service can scale horizontally**. Just add additional VM nodes if you want to increase the scale.
2. If you have different schemas on different databases in different locations, you are avoiding network performane bottlenecks in OLTP queries (Online transaction processing queries).

**Disadvantages:**

1. I see only one disadvantage since **Master Web Service acts like a Facade and it should know the internals of individual web service**. But it's not a drawback for the advantages it is offering if you consider the trade-off.

Comment: ok. I think I understood the advantages. Couple of things though, my data is very small for each schema - a few MBs at the max. I don't see the need for using another database (other than for HA). Also, if we had just one webservice serving multiple apps, wouldn't scaling it mean, just launching more clones  of this single service?

Comment: Yes. It will scale. I have provided comments for complex and huge data driven applications.

Answer (score 2):

my inputs:

1) Any specific reasons to build 2 different wars for same code? Is it only because you have two different data sources  for each of them? 
Why cant you have single application deploy with some parameterized mechanism in each request to identify which schema to get data from?

2) Why do you need a web service in first place? Why not application hook directly to database it needed.

3) Is underlying database transactional DB or some historical data? How about merging both schemas in one as one-time effort **OR** using some sort of virtualized views which picks data from 2 schemas based on input parameters.

***** edited after Jay's inputs:

My suggestion will be to have web service deployed separately from 2 web apps because it provides single place to manage code in long run. I have following additional suggestions:

1. Define your own headers in SOAP XML Schema which can give you both appContext(application making call) as well as userContext(user). Give a good thought on this aspect keeping long term view.
2. Keep SOAP request-response stateless which will give you scalability. Dont maintain any state of SOAP request at server side.
3. I have in past used a data virtualization solution (CISCO Composite)..what benefits it provides: if there are two (or more) data sources containing similar type of data(entities), it can join,cleanse & merge it virtually and expose it  as REST/SOAP based web service. Try evaluating this option as well.
   What it can further help if in future you have other consumers to access your information using plain SQL/JDBC call, they will be able to do it...also data virtualization solutions support many other interfaces to consumers like Hadoop, OData etc...again it depends on budget and other constraints of project...I am not sure if there is any effective open source data virtualization solution available or not?

Comment: 1) 2 different wars with same code - because they represent different applications. The data is different, the users are different. Think of it as having a CMS like drupal/wordpress - but you have to deploy it for unrelated departments in your company on two different urls.

Comment: 2) Web service is needed to let non-webapp users connect to the API in the future. Webservice is rest based so future users/apps can directly connect to this API

Comment: 3) Database is transactional. Why is it any different if you use a virtualized view or you query a different schema based on where the input is coming from?

Comment: my WS are REST based, not SOAP based.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about your business requirement to maintain different schemas for user data and going with webservice.

But instead of maintaining multiple wars with same code, i would suggest you to configure multiple datasources within the application and switch to datasource as per your requirement.

[This link may help you to configure multiple DS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038261/multiple-datasources-with-multiple-transaction-managers-in-spring)

If you fallow aforementioned logic, you may end up with single deployable context.

Still want to stick with multiple wars as webservice, i would suggest you to have look at [SpringBoot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) simple, container less deployable and scalable.

Comment: I have only one database, the data size is so small that it doesn't warrant another database process running on its own.

Comment: from what I understand, SpringBoot doesn't really let you easily manage (stop/restart/start) something that you run using it, unlike tomcat where you actually get finite control on webapp.

Comment: You can manage start/stop/restart through monit script, if you are dealing with UNIX kind of environment.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of opinion, both choices are okay. You should take into account the usage of the service, scaling concerns etc.

You could look at [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) as an idea, but it has to make sense from your standpoint.

About the two different apps: if the differences are only in configuration, try externalizing it ([23. Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)). This way you can have a single artifact being deployed twice.

Answer (score 2):

Given that scenario, it is a good practice having only one web service, in this way you improve the maintainability of the system because you don’t have the same code twice. If you have in the future other new similar app you don’t have to implement a new service.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1:- (Preffered)**

You should have a single web application in which will have the entire code for application UI and Repo/data interaction.

Based on the type of request dynamically switch the data source as needed. You can have at look at [Spring Dynamic datasource routing here](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

**Approach 2:-**

In case your UI has a completely different type of interactions managed by different teams, it makes sense to have separate UI components and the backend web services maintained at a same location.

Again based on the type of request you can dynamically route the datasource.

Hope this helps  :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, in my experience, it's a lot better to have them separated, it usually depends on how big and how critical your main project is.

But even if at the beginning your project isn't that big and there's only 1 person working on it, later on, as it continues to grow, if you have microservices for all the things your main project do, it will be a lot easier to maintain, rather than having many people working on the same code handling many versions of an unique project, handling many small projects is less confusing and errors are easier to find.

Plus if something fails, you can have 1 microservice down while your main still runs without interruption, it will only by denied of 1 service, instead of having everything down while you fix it.

High availability is very important in production, and having them separated helps with this.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to achieve.

If you want to encapsulate the database/schema/table, then it should really be one service for each application. The main advantage of doing this is that you could swap the database later on if there is some problem with the current one, it also simplifies caching and invalidation, etc etc.

If the database/schema/table is not encapsulated anyway, then the single service is much easier and better. Each web application just have to identify themselves, and each of them will get exactly what they need. This could be achieved by putting the query/schema information in property file, or creating db views with the same name as client, etc.

If we were to go for this approach, a question will pop up. Why bother having this layer at all? Couldn't each web application just query the db directly? If the answer is yes, then just remove the whole layer completely.

Comment: the reason for webservice is to support non-web clients in the future and to expose an API.

Comment: if you have the chance to encapsulate the db, you should definitely go for it. if not, just go with single service for each use case.

Answer (score 2):

Given your situation I'd advice going with ONE webapp (one "project") with some caveat and then consider one of the two solutions:

1) Given you are using spring, I'll assume (hope) you are using maven as well..
Make a different compilation goal and make it so that, based on the goal invoked to produce the war, the relevant properties file is different..
This way you have ONE webapp, and based on the compilation (or rather based on the properties file tied to that specific compilation) you will obtain a war tied to a specific environment&schema... You deploy an individual war for each webservice with a clean separation, though the root code is the very same and it's only one application... [CLEANER SOLUTION]
2) Make it so that you don't only get the json request but also the https certificate of the sender (thus you identify a specific "webapp" based on the https certificate exposed), and based on the certificate AND The source of the request, you ensure the source as "qualified" to receive data from schema X rather than schema Y.. You deploy ONE war only that will, at his own discretion, apply logic to reroute your "user data fetch query" to one database or the other [I DISCOURAGE THIS PRACTICE]

of course there are other approach as well, but I think these two are the most feasible..

Comment: From (1) , I understood the maven part. Packaging is not what I am worried about. I did not understand this part - "You deploy an individual war for each webservice with a clean separation" - so are you suggesting that each webapp should communicate with different webservices which are just essentially just clones of the same code base just like the webapps?

Comment: Yes, each end-of-the-line being basically different and property being possibly even externalized but that would be just icing the cake..
this way you have code that is mantained as just ONE application, and instead you decide which db/etc to query based on compilation option...
Another possible advantage of this is that you can this way decide to turn off individual webservice instead of "closing" everything when maintenance is scheduled...
But maybe it's just me.. I personally prefer the approach of a strictly modularized application where each piece has to fit a specific role.

Answer (score 1):

I would deploy to one instance. No matter what. Of course, there are circumstances where it may be necessary to deploy separately. From a best "coding" practice, one instance should be used to allow for "right once, use many".

Then...

- Define different XSD's for each AppA, AppB, etc. Marshall accordingly.
- Or, use Groovy to marshall appropriate objects as json or xml.